# C macro returning type of variable

Tags: c, function, types, macros

Could it be possible to create a macro function whose returned value be one of the predefined c variable data types? Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IND_I_ 0
#define IND_F_ 1
#define INT_FORMAT_ "%i"
#define FLOAT_FORMAT_ "%f"
// (Of course the following macros do not make the desired jobs)
// FORMAT_ macro would be used for the variable format:
#define FORMAT_( ind_ )( (ind_) == IND_I_ ? FOR_INT_ : FOR_FLOAT_ )
// VAR_TYPE_ macro would be used for 
// defining variable types and for the casting of variables:
#define VAR_TYPE_( ind_ ) ( (ind_) == IND_I_ ? int : float )

int main( void )
{
  VAR_TYPE_( IND_I_ ) first_var = 123; //here I want: int first_var = 123;
  VAR_TYPE_( IND_F_ ) second_var = 345.789;
  //Instead of:
  //printf( "int variable = " "%i" "\n", first_var );
  //I would use:
  printf( "int variable = " FORMAT_(IND_I_) "\n", first_var );
  printf( "float variable = " FORMAT_(IND_F_) "\n", second_var );
  printf( "truncated real variable = "  INT_FORMAT_ "\n", (VAR_TYPE_(IND_I_))second_var );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible in the C family.  (It *is* possible in languages with a more powerful macro system, such as Common Lisp and Rust.)

The only thing a macro can do is textual replacement.  So your

```
#define VAR_TYPE_( ind_ ) ( (ind_) == IND_I_ ? int : float )
#define IND_I_ 0
VAR_TYPE_( IND_I_ ) first_var = 123;
```

expands to

```
( (0) == 0 ) ? int : float ) first_var = 123;
```

which is a syntax error.  There is no way to make it evaluate that `?:` expression.

There is a thing you could do that would make it work whenever the argument to `VAR_TYPE_` expanded to a literal zero, one, etc.:

```
#define VAR_TYPE_(ind_) VAR_TYPE__(ind_)
#define VAR_TYPE__(ind_) VAR_TYPE__##ind_
typedef int VAR_TYPE__0;
typedef float VAR_TYPE__1;
// etc
```

... but if you're doing this at all, you probably want to allow `ind_` to be an arbitrary integer constant expression and that won't work.  You would get things like

```
VAR_TYPE_sizeof(int)==4?0:2
```

in the expansion and you'd be back to the syntax errors.

(Psst: Every time you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses, God kills a kitten.)

Comment: @zwol, do you think that there could be a workaround to my question by the use the #if, #else, #elif directives?

Comment: @Olaf It is a demonstration of exactly where the line lies between "this can be done" and "this can't be done."  It is not intended to be used in production code.

Comment: That unholy `_Generic` construct from C11 could do it. Though the format string concatenation wouldn't work, at least not in any straightforward way.

Comment: @doynax I have never needed to use `_Generic` myself, but if I'm reading C11 correctly, it can only be used to dispatch *on* a type, not to *choose* a type.  That is, it can do `(typeof x == y) ? expr_A : expr_B` but not `(boolean expression) ? type_A : type_B`.

Comment: `_Generic` is a bit worse, as it does not differentiate between compatible types.

Comment: @zwol: That is its intended use, yes, but it evaluates to arbitrary expressions at compile-time and so, say, _Generic(x, int: "%d", double: "%f") is possible except string concatenation is performed by preprocessor in an earlier pass so you'd still be screwed. Frankly the precise semantics are clunky and poorly thought out for what is an exceptionally powerful tool, bound to get abused in god-awful ways by all and sundry as soon as compiler adoption becomes widespread. I very much fear the language committee is getting invaded by the type of experts "developing" C++ </rant>

Comment: @zwol: Yes, sorry, I misread you. The types need to be compatible and so the VAR_TYPE_ part of the question would require macro pasting hacks.

Comment: @doynax I think you missed my point: `_Generic(x, ...)` dispatches on the *type* of x, whereas the OP wants to dispatch on the *value*.

Comment: @zwol: I see. I figured the type enumeration bit was just an implementation detail left over from an attempt to reach a compiling solution and that the actual problem was correctly printing arbitrary variables via `printf`.

Comment: @doynax I confess I didn't even look at the `printf` part of the question, as it seemed irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Macros r just literal replacing,so you can not do it this way.
Use c++ 11 / 14, auto type and outstream handle will fit.

Comment: "Use C++" isn't an answer for a question asked specifically for C, is it?

Comment: @MOehm yes, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no.

What do you want to achieve?
Why do you need flexible typing in C? Maybe you should move on to Java or Python then.

In your example, you already have type information, so using macros to substitute type-specific string literals are overkill.

If you want to control the types of the variables from the outside, *which I strongly oppose*, you can set up macro substitutes and inject them through a header or directly specifying them on the compiler's command line.

Example for demonstration (please don't do this at home):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* // eg.
#define TEH_TYPE double
#define TEH_TYPE_FMT "%f"
#define TEH_TYPE_ATO atof
*/
// Either, or see command line below.
/*
#define TEH_TYPE int
#define TEH_TYPE_FMT "%d"
#define TEH_TYPE_ATO atoi
*/

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    TEH_TYPE v;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        v = TEH_TYPE_ATO(argv[1]);
        printf("So your thingie is " TEH_TYPE_FMT "\n", v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can then compile it as `gcc -DTEH_TYPE=int -DTEH_TYPE_FMT='"%d"' -DTEH_TYPE_ATO=atoi main.c -o main`.

But again, please don't. I am ashamed of writing this down.

Comment: Thank you very much for your short answer. The code I wrote here is, of course, the representative part of what I wanted to do. I was wondering if  the effects I explained in my question could be achieved.